# Webhook Custom .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, webhooks

I see a few tutorials on one of the newer features of .NET '15, called WebHooks. But mainly they are for GitHub and Dropbox. Does anyone know of any resources for making a WebHook that listens to a custom third party? I'm trying to set one up in the project and the configuration is proving difficult.

I've installed the Micrsooft ASP.NET Custom package, but when I run the route that I published to on Azure and specify "https://blahblah.azurewebsites.net/api/webhooks/incoming/custom"

I get

"Could not find a valid configuration for WebHook receiver 'custom' and instance ''. The setting must be set to a value between 32 and 128 characters long."

So it seems like the resource is there, how do I set up a receiver? is that the name of the controller?

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_Slack" value="VALUE_FROM_SLACK" />
```

and then things were rosey

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below in **web.config** under `<appSettings>`

```
<add key="MS_WebHookReceiverSecret_Custom" value="12345678901234567890123456789012" />
```